# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all' Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a house's price of this link : https://www.leboncoin.fr/ventes_immobilieres/offres/ile_de_france/p-2/

And I need to know what wrong with my program ?

My program :

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open("bc.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(["prix", "code_postal", "description", "nombre_pieces", "surface"]) 
    for i in range(1, 20):
        url = "https://www.leboncoin.fr/ventes_immobilieres/offres/ile_de_france/p-%s/" % i
        soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
        repo = soup.find(class_="undefined")
        for repo in repo.find_all("li", attrs={"itemscope itemtype": "http://schema.org/Offer"}):
            prix = repo.find("span", {"itemprop": "priceCurrency"})
            prix = prix.text if prix else ""
            writer.writerow([prix])
```

I get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "nv.py", line 14, in <module>
for repo in repo.find_all("li", attrs={"itemscope itemtype": "http://schema.org/Offer"}):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to search for something that doesn't exist in the data returned by `requests`.

When you'll check `requests.get(url).text`, you'll probably see something similar to:

```
<!--
Need permission to access data? Contact: DataAccess@datadome.co
-->
<html><head><title>You have been blocked</title><style>#cmsg{animation: A 1.5s;}@keyframes A{0%{opacity:0;}99%{opacity:0;}100%{opacity:1;}}</style></head><body style="margin:0"><p id="cmsg">Please enable JS and disable any ad blocker</p><script>var dd={'cid':'AHrlqAAAAAMAptz12-9nkWQAJcs_Yg==','hsh':'05B30BD9055986BD2EE8F5A199D973','t':'fe'}</script><script src="https://ct.datadome.co/c.js"></script></body></html>
```

what results in `None` being assigned to variable `repo` and interpreter is complaining about non-existing attribute `find_all()` for the object of type `None`.

So basically you need to make sure that you have the correct data before you start processing it. You can get the data without being blocked by using *Selenium* and *ChromeDriver*, as suggested by *KunduK* in his answer. You can get *ChromeDriver* from http://chromedriver.chromium.org/

Answer (score 3):

The blocking and use of selenium has already been covered. I will show a way to get all the listings in a nice json format where you can easily extract info. If you use selenium to get to each page you can use regex to extract all the listings info on the page and pass to json.loads to generate json object, [example here](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=39d3422e2abd46078e9b621d2ff71945), you can easily parse for all the info per listing

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
import json

p = re.compile(r'({"req.*).*[^\r\n]')
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.leboncoin.fr/ventes_immobilieres/offres/ile_de_france/p-3/")
soup = bs(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
data = json.loads(p.findall(driver.page_source)[0])
listings = data['data']['ads']

for listing in listings:
    print(listing)
```

---

**Regex explanation:**

[image]

Try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/U0kQGC/1)

Answer (score 2):

Here JavaScripts render to page.You can use both selenium and beautiful soup to get the desire output.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver=webdriver.Chrome('path of the chrome driver')
driver.get("https://www.leboncoin.fr/ventes_immobilieres/offres/ile_de_france/p-2/")
soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
repo = soup.find(class_="undefined")
for repo in repo.find_all("li", attrs={"itemtype": "http://schema.org/Offer"}):
    prix = repo.find("span", {"itemprop": "priceCurrency"})
    if prix.text!='':
       print(prix.text)
```